# Reaching an image inside a JS file with thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

Inside of a massive JS file which was exported by React...

I have ONE image that is coded this way, the other are `data:image/png;base64`

```
...function(e,a,t){e.exports=t.p+"static/media/logo.png"},...
```

How can I have thymeleaf find the image inside of my static/media folder?

I know that thymeleaf works like this `<img th:src="@{/resources/images/Picture.png}" />` but this is inside of a javascript file so how would I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the image into a base64 and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use in thymeleaf by converting image on base64.You can use image by converting base 64.